# Augmenting controller with events

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I am currently writing a single page web application for a parties producing company.

My goal is to create an "Office like" application that will allow the users to open a new "party document " and edit it.

Each document will have a lot of "content pages" (like food , utilities, attractions ,suppliers etc...) and in each page there will be many fields.

Each field will have it own restrictions that should occure when it is being added , removed or edited.

I wanted to make a base JavaScript object that all other fields object will inherit from . It looks like this :

`

```
function RootComponent(name,value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = null;

    // Logic restrictions methods
    this.onChange = null;
    this.afterChange = null;
    this.onCheck = null;
    this.onDelete = null;
    this.afterDelete = null;
    this.onAdd = null;




    // Ensure we got value
    if (value !== undefined){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

`

My question is how should I augment the events of "OnChange" and such with Angular's $watch system.